# Convert Date to Day and Month (3 Letters)

Tags: php, date

I have date of each post stored in `date` field in db. The format is DD/MM/YYYY (eg : 24/12/2013). Field is VARCHAR(50)

I want to print Day and month in a page (A Blog listing page). ie like "24 DEC" (Doesnt need year)

What's the best possible way to achieve it

Note : I'm using PHP

Comment: The best advice is to correct your column type.  Always save dates as DATE type data.  Then you can enjoy all of the functional benefits that MySQL has to offer and avoid extra handling in php.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616848/2943403

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please start storing dates in Y-m-d format in `DATE` fields. Your life, and ours, would be much easier.

Until then, use this php solution:

```php
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y', '24/12/2013');
echo strtoupper($dt->format('j M')); # 24 DEC
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/228620)</kbd>

or mysql solution:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('24/12/2013','%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this: You need to reverse the date i.e. Y/m/d format.

```
 $date = strtotime('2013/12/24');
 echo date('j M ', $date);
```

Output:

```
24 Dec
```

See in [PHP Date Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

that should do it:

```
echo date_format($date,"d M");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string using

```
$dateArray = explode("/", $date);
```

and you'll have

```
$year = $dateArray[2];
$month = $dateArray[1];
$day = $dateArray[0];
```

Maybe a better way is to store PHP timestamp in the dB datefield. Then you can in addition extract hours, minutes and seconds from one string.

Answer (score 1):

simply do this

```
echo date('M j,Y');
```

it will give result

```
Jun 3,2020
```

Answer (score 0):

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y', '18/10/2016');

echo strtoupper($dt->format('d M'));