# MYSQL to print the date in pieces on the screen

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I want to print the dates from the database. But when I print the dates, I just want to take the **day** that belongs to that month.

This process can be done by breaking it with "**PHP Explode**". But I want to do this without using "**PHP Explode**". Can it be implemented directly with **SQL code**?

**MYSQL TABLE;**

```
id   no    date   
1    1     2019-11-01    
2    1     2019-11-02    
3    4     2019-11-03    
4    1     2019-11-04
```

**MY SQL CODE;**

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE no = '1'
```

**MY PHP CODE;**

```
foreach ( $sql as $index => $value )
{
  echo $value['date'];
}
```

**Desired Result;**

```
01
02
04
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616746/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043824/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d') AS day
FROM user
WHERE no = '1'
ORDER BY date;
```

### Demo